Finitely points of intersection between an algebraic curve and a complex analytic funtion
We have the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{p(x,y)}{q(x,y)}$ where $p(x,y)$ and $q(x,y)$ are complex polynomails. If we have an analytic solution for this differential equation, $y=\varphi(x)$, then $\varphi$ has ramification points in $\{q(x,y)=0\}$. The affirmation says that the set $G_{\varphi}\cap V(q)=\{q(x,\varphi(x))=0\}$ form at most countable sets in the $x$-plane, but I don´t unserstand how to prove it.
I was thinking to use the unity theorem for analytic funtions, suppose that we have infity numbers of points and use the compactness in $\mathbb{C}^{*}$ to give a subsucession that converges and say that $q(x,\varphi(x))=0$ it's identically cero.
